# DOM Error in IE8, site crashes but no js errors

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-8

I've a big issue in IE8 on Windows XP.

[This is my website](http://clients.treestarwebdesign.be/savemak/bank) and he crashes after a couple a clicks.

I don't get js errors but in the doctype he says unknown. No quirksmode,  no Internet Explorer.

What could be the problem?

Kind regards